# How does ServiceStack handle concurrent calls?

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

How does ServiceStack handle concurrent calls? I'm looking for equivalent of ConcurrencyMode.Multiple in WCF.

My WCF services have this attribute set:

```
   [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
```

Do I need to enable anything in ServiceStack to get it to use multiple threads for each call?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ServiceStack doesn't have a configurable concurrency model per AppHost, it is dependent upon the AppHost you choose to host your ServiceStack services with:

#### ASP.NET Host (AppHostBase)

For ASP.NET web hosts, ServiceStack **doesn't create any new threads** itself, the requests are simply handled on the same IIS/Nginx/etc ASP.NET HTTP WebWorker that handles the request.

#### HttpListener Self-Host (AppHostHttpListenerBase)

ServiceStack only creates a new thread on **Startup** when you call `new AppHost().Start(url)`. There are no new threads created at run-time, i.e. the request is handled on the HttpListener async callback thread.

#### HttpListener Long Running Self-Host (AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase)

This is another Self-Host HttpListener option for ServiceStack that uses its own managed ThreadPool to execute the request on (free-ing up the HttpListener async callback thread). The default poolSize of the ThreadPool is **500** threads, though this is configurable in the `AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase(poolSize)` constructor.

#### RedisMQ Host (RedisMqServer)

A good option for managing long-running tasks is to delegate requests to a [Redis MQ Host](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-redis) which is a light-weight MQ Server allowing you to defer and process requests in managed background threads. By default the RedisMqServer spawns a single background thread for each Message type (i.e. Request), though this is configurable on start-up, e.g: in the example below **2 background threads** are used to handle `PostTwitter` requests, whilst only 1 background thread each is used to process `CallFacebook` and `EmailMessage` requests:

```
mq.RegisterHandler<PostTwitter>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage, noOfThreads:2);
mq.RegisterHandler<CallFacebook>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);
mq.RegisterHandler<EmailMessage>(ServiceController.ExecuteMessage);
```

Comment: So with an AppHostBase hosted on IIS, if 4 clients simultaneously call the same service are each served at the same time, or are they handled one after another? I initially thought WCF would handle each request at the same time, but in fact by default it works sequentially processing one request at a time. A very interesting article explaining the WCF concurrency model is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and

Comment: IIS handles the multi-threading of the HTTP Worker threads just as it does with every other ASP.NET web application (which is all that ServiceStack is when hosted in ASP.NET). IIS is a multi-threaded Web Server which handles requests concurrently.

Comment: Is this answer just copy'n'paste from [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Concurrency-model) without indication of source or was it the other way around?

Comment: @mono68 I'm the author of both, initially answered here before adding it to the docs.