# ServiceStack: Non blocking request handling

Tags: .net, web-services, servicestack, nonblocking

I'm looking for a way to handle non-blocking requests in a service based on the ServiceStack framework. So I've seen there's the AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase class (I need a self hosted app at the moment) but there's not any nice example how to use this class.

Let's look at a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

using ServiceStack.ServiceHost;
using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;
using ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints;


public class Hello
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse
{
    public String Result { get; set; }
}

public class HelloService : Service
{
    public Object Any(Hello request)
    {
        //Emulate a long operation
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Message from " + request.Name };
    }
}

public class HelloAppHost : AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase 
{
    public HelloAppHost()
        : base("Hello App Services", typeof(HelloService).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        Routes
            .Add<Hello>("/hello")
            .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name}");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var appHost = new HelloAppHost();
        appHost.Init();
        appHost.Start("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

So if I run the app and make two requests they will be executed in the serial mode and there'll be a delay between responses about 10 seconds. So is there a way to execute non-blocking requests (better if there's a self host app solution).

P.S.: I know there's a Redis based solution but it's not suitable for some reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread.sleep is what is causing the 10 second delay.  Web services are not neccesarily made to be multithreaded applications.  What I have found is make the response really quick by caching up common responses and you shouldnt have a wait time nearly as long as the thread sleep you have there currently.

Comment: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Concurrency-model Here is an interesting link that can probably explain it better than i did.

Comment: there's a problem my service has to request another services before return a response. so it really can take much time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238680/how-does-servicestack-handle-concurrent-calls 
This outlines the ways to servicestack can handle concurrent calls

Comment: So I've seen this and I'm interested in how to create a non-blocking service using AppHostHttpListenerLongRunningBase. As you see I tried to use this class but it's not working at the moment.

Comment: Just to be clear the thread.sleep is to mimic what you are seeing and is not actually in the service, correct?

Comment: Yep. But in a real app I have to make requests to other services(not standard services like rest or so but making a tcp connection pool that communicates using a special protocol format). So I want to write a wrapper above this low level architecture. Requests from tcp connection can really take much time and I dont want to block the service during these calls.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31426/discussion-between-maxfx-and-tyler-smith)