# Synchronised requests enforced from ServiceStack 3 configuration

Tags: asp.net, concurrency, synchronization, httprequest, servicestack

I have an ASP.NET application, using NGINX as a server and Servicestack 3.

When it comes to PUT requests, I'd like them to be synchronously processed as they come in to Servicestack from the NGINX server (never have multiple requests processed at the same time, since this could lead to them finishing their job in a different order from the one they were called in). As I understand it, it's possible to control the number of threads being used for incoming requests - If I'd be able to restrict that number to 1, I imagine I'd get the result that I want.

How would I go about achieving this from the level of ServiceStack configuration (if it's even possible - [the accepted response from this question is making me think it isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238680/how-does-servicestack-handle-concurrent-calls); but then if that's true, how am I supposed to enforce synchronisation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely you want to block the whole HTTP Server, that could cause all other requests to fail.

Have you just tried using a singleton lock? e.g. you could use the Type of your Service for this:

```
lock (typeof(MyService))
{
}
```

But locking in a Web Server like this is generally a bad idea, you should think of using some kind of optimistic concurrency control where it throws an error when trying to update a stale record. e.g. In OrmLite you can use its [RowVersion feature for optimistic concurrency](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#optimistic-concurrency) where clients send the RowVersion which represents the state of the record they have and if it's been updated since OrmLite will throw a `OptimisticConcurrencyException` which in ServiceStack automatically gets converted to a **409 Conflict** HTTP Error Response.

Comment: Yes, singleton lock is doable; I was looking to get this to work just by configuring Servicestack though. Thank you for telling me about optimistic concurrency, I'm going to look into it; The thing is I don't want errors being thrown. What I want to happen is for my PUT requests to be served in the order they come in, waiting for eachother in a queue.

Comment: @Claudiu it's a really bad idea to lock HTTP Server requests, locking as above can Queue Requests but that doesn't help when the queued Requests are operating on modified/stale data which is why optimistic concurrency is important. It sounds like what you really want is to use a MQ where requests are executed FIFO and you can configure it to use a single thread so they're executed one at a time without locking infrastructure resources and severely hurting your systems perf/throughput.

Comment: Yes, things are getting a bit clearer now; I think [RedisMQ](http://docs.servicestack.net/redis-mq#easily-testable-and-swappable) is the solution to my problem! It even says so on [Servicestack's Concurrency Model chapter](http://docs.servicestack.net/concurrency-model). Some more pretty good explanations of Redis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net/2760282#2760282). Thanks a lot, @mythz!

Comment: Ended up just sticking with a singleton lock.