# ServiceStack: Multithreading using AppSelfHostBase - can it handle concurrent calls?

Tags: servicestack

I read [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238680/how-does-servicestack-handle-concurrent-calls), but it wasnt immediately clear to me how the AppSelfHostBase is handling the same question (its not explicitly mentioned ni the SO post):

Does the `AppSelfHostBase` allow for concurrent request to be handled?

I am guessing yes, as it inherits from `AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase` which implies some form of ThreadPool (?), but its not immediately clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes `AppHostHttpListenerPoolBase` executes each request on a different Thread free-ing up the HttpListener worker request thread.

The recommendation would now be to use the leaner/faster ASP.NET Core (on either .NET Core or .NET Framework) but if you want to use self-host HttpListener you can also consider the [SmartThreadPool.AppSelfHostBase](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.NetFramework/SmartThreadPool/AppSelfHostBase.cs) in the [ServiceStack.NetFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.NetFramework) NuGet package which uses the more optimal [SmartThreadPool](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool).

Comment: Thanks! We are actually in the process of migrating to .NET Core, so we'll see how that works out.